# substraction : replace blank with zero

Tags: char

```
// this is a substraction example
    int x=3098;
    int z=3088;
    int somme=x-z;
    char buffer[4];

// convert int to char
    itoa(somme,buffer,10);

// I want to push the buffer value on a char table like this "**0010**" not 
// like "**10**"
```

Comment: Mention the programming language, please.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to use a formater, standard ones in C are of `printf` family. Take care of the length of the array because if you want to store a string of length *n* you need an array of length *n+1* (c-strings are Null-terminated). Thus:

```
// this is a substraction example
int x=3098;
int z=3088;
int somme=x-z;
char buffer[5];
sprintf(buffer,"%04d",somme);
```

will fit your needs. It means to format the integer `somme` as (`%04d`) decimal representation of length 4 padded with leading zeros if needed, and to store the result in memory starting at the beginning of `buffer`.